# how to retry SQL update statements until it got success using python

Tags: python, sql

want to execute try block multiple times until it return *success* for sql update statements using python

'''

```
        exec_up_2a = "Exec usp_update_reco_status_2a1 @reco_id = ?,@companyid=?"
        cursor.execute( exec_up_2a, [Reco_id,company_id] )
       # cursor.execute(exec_up_2a, Reco_id ) 
        conn.commit()
        logger.info("Reco status updation in 2A")
        exec_up_pr = "Exec usp_update_reco_status_pr1 @reco_id = ?,@companyid=?"
        cursor.execute(exec_up_pr, [Reco_id,company_id] ) 
        logger.info("Reco status updation in PR Done")
        print('Reco status in 2A & PR Done')
        conn.commit()
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

After calling `cursor.execute()`, you can use `cursor.rowcount` to test the success of update/insert statements.

**Approach:**

- Assign a default value `(=0)` to a variable called `affected_rows`
- Insert your `try` block inside a `while` loop, checking for `affected_rows < 1` (that means update has failed).
- After calling `cursor.execute()`, update `affected_rows` variable using `cursor.rowcount`

  ```
  affected_rows = 0
  while affected_rows < 1:
    try:
        # connect
         exec_up_2a = "Exec usp_update_reco_status_2a1 @reco_id = ?,@companyid=?"
        cursor.execute( exec_up_2a, [Reco_id,company_id] )
        # cursor.execute(exec_up_2a, Reco_id ) 
        conn.commit()
        logger.info("Reco status updation in 2A")
        exec_up_pr = "Exec usp_update_reco_status_pr1 @reco_id = ?,@companyid=?"
        cursor.execute(exec_up_pr, [Reco_id,company_id] ) 

        affected_rows = cursor.rowcount 

        logger.info("Reco status updation in PR Done")
        print('Reco status in 2A & PR Done')
        conn.commit()
    except:
         pass
  ```

But remember, in case of repeated failures, this code will run as an infinite loop.